# why is the max number of Nodes mod(N/m) + mod(N/m^2) + 1 in R-tree?

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis

I am going through Antonin Guttman's paper on R-tree. It mentions the max no of nodes given N index records in an R-tree is `|N/m| + |N/m^2| + 1`.

If there are N index records and if we choose to have minimum number of entries (m) in each node, wouldn't we just need N/m nodes at max? Why do we also have N/m^2 + 1?

[Here's a link to the paper](http://www-db.deis.unibo.it/courses/SI-LS/papers/Gut84.pdf)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the relevant excerpt of that paper.

> The height of an R-tree containing $N$ index records is at most $\lceil\log_m N\rceil$, because the branching factor of each node is at least $m$. The maximum number of
>   nodes is $\lceil\frac Nm\rceil + \lceil\frac N{m^2}\rceil + \cdots + 1$. Worst-case space utilization for all nodes except
>   the root is $\frac mM$.

The paper you saw is so fuzzy that you mistook the formula as $|\frac Nm| + |\frac N{m^2}| + 1$.

How to explain the correct formula? Since all leaves are on the same level and each leaf-node contains at least $m$ index records, there are at most $\lceil\frac Nm\rceil$ leaf nodes. The number of the parents of all leaf nodes is at most $\lceil\frac{\frac Nm}m\rceil=\lceil\frac N{m^2}\rceil$. And so on.

Here is [a copy of that paper](https://apps.dtic.mil/dtic/tr/fulltext/u2/a168531.pdf) that is more legible.